# Pass a reference to a class that is not instantiated

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I have a class and I would like to pass a reference of the class to a function that takes that reference as a parameter. The function will create an instance of the class. I am not sure how to define the function's parameter or how to pass a reference to the class. For example:

```
class User {
  var name: String = ""
}

fun processUser(userClass: User) {
  // Create an instance of User
  val user = userClass()
  user.name = "John Doe"
}

// Call the function. Something like this...
processUser(User.java)
```

I know that this could be done using KClass but was wondering if this could be done with the specific class that I want to instantiate, which in this case is User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your `processUser()` function expects at the moment is an **instance** of User. What you actually want to receive is a function that creates a User. So it should be

```
fun processUser(userSupplier: () -> User) {
    // Create an instance of User
    val user = userSupplier()
    user.name = "John Doe"
}

fun main() {
    processUser { User() }
    // or simply via a constructor reference
    processUser(::User)
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I am only use to seeing lambdas being used as lambda functions when passed as parameters. This is first time I've seen it use to pass a class reference.

Comment: It doesn't pass a class reference. It passes a *constructor* reference.

Comment: I assume that this solution would not work if you had multiple constructors?

Comment: You could just try it to find out. Yes, it would work, because it would infer which constructor you want to refer to (the one without arguments)